# Get annotations from interface using reflections

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have the next interface:

```
public interface AG {
    @Params(param = {"user","userN"})
    public String addUse(){}
}
```

Now, I want to get the annotaion in reflection, so I wrote the next:

```
    Method[] methods = AG.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i<methods.length; i++){
        String name = methods[i].getName();
        if (name.equals("addUse")){
            Method method = methods[i];
            Annotation[] annotaions = method.getAnnotations();}}
```

I see that the annotaions is an empty set (when the method is `addUse`). What can be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will work only for annotations that have the right [retention policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) to be accessible for introspection at runtime. In particular, it should be `RUNTIME`, like so:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Params {
...
```

The [retention policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html), as the name suggests, determines until what time the information about the annotation is preserved, with the corresponding bytecode:

- [`SOURCE`: not at all](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#SOURCE) (generates no bytecode for the annotation).
- [`CLASS`: in the classfile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#CLASS) (generates a `RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations` reference to the annotation type),
- [`RUNTIME`: available to the code running in the VM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#RUNTIME) (generates a `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations` reference to the annotation type).

Note that this means that, theoretically, `CLASS`-retention annotations *could* be made available by the VM. In practice, however, this is not the case (certainly not on the Oracle JVM).